# Why should name attribute not be set if http-equiv is set in meta tag?

Tags: html, meta-tags, http-equiv

I am stuck on one sentence while reading about **meta tag** in html that **"If the `http-equiv` attribute is set, the `name` attribute should not be set"** . I've done search about this but I couldn't find any reason behind this.

Would anyone tell the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The http-equiv you can think of it like an instruction for the browser (refresh, Set-Cookie, expiers)...by setting an http-equiv property you are changing browser behavior.

For name attribute, on the other hand, you are simply describing something (title, keywords, etc.).

An action and a description are different types of ideas.

Comment: but is there any problem if we put these attributes together ?

Comment: Yes, do not put them together. There's no reason to.